# OLE DB SOURCE truncation

Tags: ssis

I have a OLE DB Source and a Flat file Destination set of objects on my SSIS package. I am getting a warning on the OLE DB object about data truncation for a field. The field is called Pricing_Specialist_c. It is part of a subquery.
in the below query. When I run the query using the preview inside the ole db edit window, there is no truncation. I set the length of the field in question to 100 characters as a string in the connection. However, in the flat file it is truncated at about 15 characters. why is this?
Heres the query (with some of the extra stuff removed)

```
SELECT
dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT AS 'Account_Number__c',
OEM AS 'OEM_c',
(SELECT NAME from USERINFO where SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.SalesTaker = USERINFO.NETWORKALIAS) as 'Pricing_Specialist_c'        
FROM
    dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.CONTACTPERSON ON dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID = dbo.CONTACTPERSON.CONTACTPERSONID
WHERE
    CREATEDDATE >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 30, 101)
    OR
    --Only update quotes that were created in 2013 or after
    (MODIFIEDDATE >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 30, 101)
    AND
    YEAR(CREATEDDATE) > 2012)
```

Comment: Do you have any data conversions or derived columns in between your source and destination? Can double click the flow immediately before your destination to ensure its 100?

Comment: Have you checked the `OLE DB` object `Advanced Editor for OLE DB Source` to see what the output data type length?